# Swapping pairs in a list in an Iterative and recursive way -Python3

Tags: python, list, recursion

I need to write a function that given an input list, all adjacent elements in the list are swapped with each other. If the length of the list is odd, then the last element just stays put. I wrote the function iteratively, like so:

```
>>>def swap(nums):
     for i in range(0,len(nums),2):
         try:
             nums[i],nums[i+1] = nums[i+1], nums[i]
         except:
             pass
     return nums

>>>swap([1,2,3,4,5])
[2, 1, 4, 3, 5]
```

I used the exact same logic as before for the recursive version:

```
def swap(nums, c=0):
    try:
        nums[c], nums[c+1] = nums[c+1], nums[c]
        return swap(nums, c+2)
    except:
        return nums
```

Although both work, I feel like I'm cheating a bit with these `try/except` blocks, and I won't become a better programmer by using them all the time. Can anybody give me suggestions on how to approach these problems without relying on `try/except` blocks?

Comment: Your second function isn't really exploiting the idea behind recursion. Recursion often takes *one step* in simplifying the problem and then passes the simplified problem to itself (next recursion step). The basic structure of a recursive function is always: 1. stop condition; 2. recursion step. The way to do recusion for your problem is to check if the length <2 (stop condition) and otherwise swap the first two elements and append the result of the nums[2:] recusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the iterative version, you can use `range(0, len(nums)-1, 2)` to keep looping till the item before last as the following:

```
def swap(nums):
    for i in range(0, len(nums) - 1, 2):
        nums[i], nums[i + 1] = nums[i + 1], nums[i]
    return nums
```

And in the recursive version, you can check `if c >= len(nums) - 1` to check if you have reached last item:

```
def swap(nums, c=0):
    if c >= len(nums) - 1:
        return nums
    nums[c], nums[c+1] = nums[c+1], nums[c]
    return swap(nums, c+2)
```

this way you can avoid `try/except` because you will not raise index out of range `exception`. And for reference, if you want to use `try/except` it is better to use `except IndexError:` instead of general `except:`.

Input:

```
print(swap([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
print(swap([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
[2, 1, 4, 3, 5]
```

EDIT:

As @agtoever mentioned, you can modify the recursive version to be:

```
def swap(nums):
    if len(nums) < 2:
        return nums
    return [nums[1], nums[0]] + swap(nums[2:])
```

Comment: From my understanding if the list is even, all elements should half their positions swapped, your iterative solution would ignore the last element in an even length list

Comment: @Teo No it wouldn't, I will edit the answer to include input/output

Comment: Great answer. One question: why do you add the second parameter, while you can also do: `return [nums[1], nums[0]] + swap(nums[2:])`? And test for `len(nums)<2` to `return nums`? This strengthens the recursion idea (in each step a smaller list is passed) and drops the second parameter.

Comment: @agtoever You are correct, but the OP was asking about removing the `try/except` blocks. I will however update the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Iteratively:**

```
for i in range(0, len(nums) - (len(nums) % 2), 2): #Skips the last element in an odd length list
  nums[c], nums[c+1] = nums[c + 1], nums[c]
```

**Recursively:**

```
import math

def swap(nums):
  if len(nums) == 2:
    return [nums[1], nums[0]]
  if len(nums) == 1:
    return nums[0]
  half = int(math.ceil(len(nums) / 2.0))
  return swap(nums[:half]) + swap(nums[half:])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def swap(li):
  if len(li) < 2:
    return li
  else:
    return [li[1], li[0]] + swap(li[2:])
```

or

```
def swap(li):
  def swap_iter(inlist, out):
    if len(inlist) < 2:
      return out + inlist
    else:
      return swap_iter(inlist[2:], out + [inlist[1], inlist[0]])
  return swap_iter(li, [])
```